# Error while trying to use Hibernate to perform SELECT operation

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Im a newbie to hibernate and I'm facing an error while trying  to use Hibernate to select data from a table,
I've tried two approaches for this and faced the following errors .

Approach 1

```
   private static void queryPerson(Session session) {

    String SQL_QUERY ="Select person.ID as ID,person.NAME as NAME ,person.SURNAME AS SURNAME,person.ADDRESS  as ADDRESS From person";
         Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
         for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();){
         Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();
         System.out.println("ID: " + row[0]);
         System.out.println("Name: " + row[1]);
         System.out.println("Amount: " + row[2]);
         session.getTransaction().commit();
         }
```

This throws the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: person is not mapped [Select person.ID as ID,person.NAME as NAME ,person.SURNAME AS SURNAME,person.ADDRESS  as ADDRESS From person]
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:111)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:327)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3441)
```

Approach 2:

```
  private static void queryPerson(Session session) {
  Query query = session.createQuery("from Person");                 
    List <Person>list = query.list();
    java.util.Iterator<Person> iter = list.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {

        Person person = iter.next();
        System.out.println("Person: \"" + person.getName() +"\", " + person.getSurname() +"\", " +person.getAddress());
  session.getTransaction().commit();

    }
```

Throws the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column person0_.id does not exist
Position: 8
at    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
at   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
```

It would be great if anyone could point out where Im going wrong.
Thanks!
EDIT:
Person.hbm.xml

```
<class name="com.sample.Person" table="Person">

    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="name">
        <column name="NAME" length="16" not-null="false" />
    </property>

    <property name="surname">
        <column name="SURNAME" length="16" not-null="false" />
    </property>

    <property name="address">
        <column name="ADDRESS" length="16" not-null="false" />
    </property>

</class>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <!-- hibernate dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>


    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testDB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property> 
    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

    <!-- Automatic schema creation (begin) === -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>


    <!-- Simple memory-only cache -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- ############################################ -->
    <!-- # mapping files with external dependencies # -->
    <!-- ############################################ -->

    <mapping resource="com/sample/Person.hbm.xml" />

</session-factory>
```

EDIT: Here is the Person class that Im using:

```
 package com.sample;

 public class Person {
  Long id;
   String name;
   String surname;
   String address;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
private void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
 }
}
```

Comment: person is not mapped..maybe it should be Person? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-casesensitivity

Comment: Added data to the question, do have a look!

Comment: In first case you can call "createSQLQuery" as it looks like a native sql query to me.

Comment: MySQLInnoDBDialect is used only for MySQL databases, if you have Postgres, you should change it.

Comment: ^above please have a look at the comments on @Adi's answer

Comment: I tried that: replaced
Person person=iter.next() with Person person=new Person(); however the following error persists:
Missing sequence or table: hibernate_sequence
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing sequence or table: hibernate_sequence
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1354)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

person.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.sample.Person" table="Person">
      <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="name">
        <column name="NAME" length="16" not-null="false" />
    </property>

    <property name="surname">
        <column name="SURNAME" length="16" not-null="false" />
    </property>

    <property name="address">
        <column name="ADDRESS" length="16" not-null="false" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
      ...your database configurations and mapping file...

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
public class HibernateUtil {

        private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        static {
            try {
                // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
                // ------ --- -------------- ---- -----------------
                sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                        .buildSessionFactory();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
                // ---- ---- --- --- --- ---------- -- -- ----- -- ---------
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Get the configured session factory
         * 
         * @return session factory
         */
        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }
```

An example:

```
public class PersonExample{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            System.out.println("Starting select");
            List<Person> persons= session.createSQLQuery("select {p.*} from Person p").addEntity("p", Person.class).list();
            for (Iterator<Person> it = persons.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Person stObject = it.next();
               System.out.println("ID: " + stObject.getId());
               System.out.println("Surname: " + stObject.getSurname());
               System.out.println("Name: " + stObject.getName());
               System.out.println("Address: " + stObject.getAddress());
            }
            System.out.println("Finished select");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Actual contact insertion will happen at this step
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the example : But on trying this I get:
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column p.id does not exist
  Position: 8.
Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Yes I do have a field id in the Person class and a column as well

Comment: Here's the script of the table im using

CREATE TABLE person
(
  "ID" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('hibernate_sequence'::regclass),
  "name" character varying,
  surname character varying,
  address character varying,
  CONSTRAINT person_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE person OWNER TO postgres;
and as for autoincrement, I dont think postgresql offers that, so Im making the pkey refer to a sequence.

Comment: making that^ change in the Person.hbm.xml along with  corrected approach 1-causes the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:63)

Comment: should I then rename the sequence in the DB from 'hibernate_sequence' to 'person_id_seq'?EDIT: Tried that, and replaced the id fragment in Person.hbm.xml and  and face the same error as before!

Comment: Hibernate: select nextval ('person_id_seq')
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:63)
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:280)
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:182)
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile....
 at com.sample.TestPerson.queryPerson(TestPerson.java:26)
 at com.sample.TestPerson.main(TestPerson.java:18)

Comment: Script of the table:-- Table: person

-- DROP TABLE person;

CREATE TABLE person
(
  "ID" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('person_id_seq'::regclass),
  "name" character varying,
  surname character varying,
  address character varying,
  CONSTRAINT person_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE person OWNER TO postgres;
And the sequence:
CREATE SEQUENCE person_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 6
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE person_id_seq OWNER TO postgres;

Comment: try to change id type to serial, remove all the other stuff

Comment: did that and removed sequence from Person.hbm.xml and now I get the following error:
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing sequence or table: hibernate_sequence
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: replace validate with create in     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
This will automatically create your table.

Comment: did that and got the same node cannot be traversed error.
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:63)
The element in Person.hbm.xml is :  <id name="id" column="id" > <generator class="sequence">  </generator> </id>.
Am I missing something?

Comment: you should add the sequence name in the xml, like before

Comment: see this tutorial, it may help: http://www.laliluna.de/articles/java-persistence-hibernate/first-hibernate-example-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you provide the class Person with the annotation @Entity ?

HQL is different from SQL.  I think there is something wrong with your query:

> String SQL_QUERY ="Select person.ID as ID,person.NAME as NAME ,person.SURNAME AS SURNAME,person.ADDRESS  as ADDRESS From person";

Try something like:
HQL:  select person.id, person.name, person.surname, person.address from Person as person

Always uppercase for table names, matching your class names.
For the column names, these have to match your instance variables.

Update (Hibernate mapping test with Unitils):

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner;
import org.unitils.orm.hibernate.HibernateUnitils;
import org.unitils.spring.annotation.SpringApplicationContext;

/**
 * Unitils mapping test class.
 * 
 */
@SpringApplicationContext({ "spring.xml" })
@RunWith(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.class)
public class HibernateMappingTest {

    @Test
    public void testMappingToDatabase() {
        HibernateUnitils.assertMappingWithDatabaseConsistent();
    }
```

}

Comment: Im trying to do it without annotations. As the example I followed didn't mention any reference to them

Comment: @kclaes he/she did in approach 2.

Comment: @kclaes, that issue has been resolved, but now I get an error about the sequence :error persists: Missing sequence or table: hibernate_sequence Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing sequence or table: hibernate_sequence at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1354) –

Comment: @KodeSeeker
Maybe you have to change your hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property to update:

 <bean id="hibernateProperties"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="properties">  
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
    <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
   </props>  
  </property>
 </bean>

Comment: @kclaes, I fixed that error by creating a sequence by the name' hibernate_sequence' to create the ID, but now I get the following error:org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92) Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column p.id does not exist Position: 8. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: @KodeSeeker
Did you annotate the field "id" in Person like this:
 @ Id
 @ GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @ Column(name = "BlahBlahId")
 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }

Comment: Nope havent used annotations at all. The example I followed didnt suggest them, are they mandatory?

Comment: @KodeSeeker nope, not mandatory, just more easier to work with than hibernate xml mapping file I think. :) 
If the ERROR: column p.id does not exist is still there, look in your DB. Is there a column id present, than your query is wrong. If there isn't a column id present, than your mapping file is probably wrong.
Did you do a mapping test?  (see my updated answer above)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7667/discussion-between-kodeseeker-and-kclaes)

Answer (score 1):

The name of the mapped class and alias is missing. Your query should be,

```
Select person.ID as ID,person.NAME as NAME ,person.SURNAME AS SURNAME,person.ADDRESS  as ADDRESS From Person as person
```

Notice the capital 'P' in 'From Person'. I assume code bases in approach 1 and approach 2 is same. In approach 2 class name is 'Person' not 'person' unless your intention is to execute native sql. In that cases, you should be calling,`session.createSQLQuery` and try if you are able to execute same query on db directly.

From approach 2 exception trace, your mapping is wrong. Verify whether table exists and column names are correct in mapping.

Comment: :Tried your approach and got the following error(Im assuming the query you suggested was for approach 1):
nitial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing sequence or table: hibernate_sequence
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing sequence or table: hibernate_sequence.. Where should I create this sequence?

Comment: @Adi- Did that and got the following error:
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
aused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into Person (NAME, SURNAME, ADDRESS, ID) values ('Barak', 'Obhama', 'White House', '1') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.

Seems like Im going around in circles :s